# Ruby on Rails: getting the max value from a DB column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Currently I can make the straight-up SQL query on my DB:

```sql
SELECT MAX(bar) FROM table_name
```

And it returns with the max value in that table. When I make what I consider to be an equivalent call in Rails, however, it does not work. I am calling:

```rb
Bar.all(:select => "Max(bar)")
```

This simply returns with:

```rb
[#<Bar >]
```

In the column I'm calling on is a series of identifying numbers, I'm looking for the largest one. Is there some other way of accessing this in Rails?

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Assuming your model name is `Bar` and it has a column named `bar`, this should work:

```
Bar.maximum(:bar)
```

See the excellent Rails Guides section on [Calculations :: Maximum](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#maximum) for more info.

Comment: Ah ha! Right you are, that did it. I'll check your answer off as the one soon as SO will let me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

one more way

```
Bar.select("Max(bar) as max_bar").first.max_bar
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? More verbose, and executes the exact same query as `Bar.maximum(:bar)` so I see no reason to "recommend" this answer at all ...

Comment: for example, if you want both min and max: `Bar.select("MAX(bar) max_bar, MIN(bar) min_bat").first.attributes`

Comment: The person asking the question only wanted max.

Comment: He did provide an correct answer for the question. Probably it's not the best answer, but he did nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I think it has value as it shows an example of using a function inside of .select which is knowledge that could be helpful in executing a similar query where you want to select multiple things.